# c#winforms развертывание (deployment ) приложение с mysql баз данных на других компьютерах в одной сети

Tags: c#

уважаемые люди, хочу развертывать приложение с базы данных Mysql на других компьютерах в одной сети , через debug пользователи на своих компьютерах авторизуются в базу данных. теперь хочу все упаковать в один .Exe как установочный файл. clickonce не работает. подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать

Comment: [1](https://habr.com/ru/post/253819/), [2](https://habr.com/ru/company/crosstech/blog/543032/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам в комментариях aeopt посоветовал статью, которая описывает современый способ решения проблемы.

Но если "не хочется возиться" - есть еще один способ. Дело в том, что "исторически" в Visual Studio был такой тип проектов - "Setup project".

Идея там простая: Вы в solution добавляете Setup project. Потом в этот Setup project добавляете "тот проект, из которого надо сдалть setup". Потом там можно добавить еще всякие иконки, ярлыки, котроые надо поставить пользователю на рабочий стол и т.п.

Но почему то этот тип проектов был выкинут из сравнительно свежих версий студии.

Чтобы его вернуть - надо установить Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects extension.

Устанавливается этот extension c https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/, вот [ссылка](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects) для 2017-2019 студии, там же в начале идёт ссылка для 2022-й студии.

[Вот](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Mfp2EXmVNI) ссылка на ролик на ютьюбе, где показан процесс "как сделать сетап".

По большому счету, этот способ - простой, просто всё, что нужно, упаковывается в один msi-файл. После некоторых экспериментов у Вас всё должно получиться!

И еще одно замечание.

Как я понял, у Вас много пользователей должно работать с одной базой данных. Постарайтесь заранее проверить, что эта база данных доступна по сети, и в приложении указан именно "сетевой путь доступа" к базе. Иначе может получиться так, что на машине разработчика, где находится и приложение, и база - всё работает, а на машине пользователя, где находится только приложение - оно не может подключиться к базе.

Comment: благодарю за развёрнутый ответ , но почему-то у меня не получается развернуть на других компьютерах , ошибка возникает,  в Connectionstring указан сетевой путь ,то есть IP адрес , если перекинуть Debug папку другим компьютерам все прекрасно работает , только вот с Setup project возникают ошибки. возможно что-то я не включаю в проект

Comment: @Misterjunior дополните вопрос, укажите все детали. Что делаете, и что получается, и что должно получиться. Где расположена БД, где клиент, сколько клиентов у БД. Логи ошибок, код, который не работает, всё что есть, относящееся к проблеме. Как отвечать на проблему, которую вы не обозначили?

Comment: хорошо, сейчас исправлю вопрос

Comment: я бы даже написал другой вопрос - у Вас ведь теперь не со сборкой сетапа проблема возникает?

Comment: нет, установочный файл выходит нормально , и в моем компьютере (где установлен VS и локальный сервер все прекрасно устанавливается и открывается )

Comment: > в моем компьютере (где установлен VS и локальный сервер все прекрасно устанавливается и открывается ) - Ну, тогда у Вас проблема с коннектом к базе по сети. Думаю, что нужен другой вопрос, и в нём нужны уже фразменты conection string и т.п.

Comment: я щас исправлю вопрос ,  ошибки щас выложу , интернет медленный долго грузится